# Install and use Hovercraft on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: python, python3, pip

I am trying to use [hovercraft](https://regebro.github.io/hovercraft/#/step-1) on my Ubuntu 14.10 laptop. This is a python script, and I'm not that familiar with python... So here is what I've done:

- first, I installed hovercraft using `sudo pip install hovercraft`
- then I tried hovercraft using `hovercraft mytest.rst outdir`: ***it ran*** but led me to errors, and I found that hovercraft is a **python 3** only script.
- so, I installed python3-pip using apt: `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` and installed hovercraft in python3 with `sudo pip3 install hovercraft`
- but python3 was not my default python interpreter, so I added `alias python=python3` to my .bashrc

Now, when I type python -V, I get **Python 3.4.2**. But... typing `hovercraft mytest.rst outdir` gives me nothing, as hovercraft is not a known command.

So here is my question: **how do I make python 3 scripts installed with pip3 visible in my default classpath ?**

(or maybe I have another problem you can point me out :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem: both pip and pip3 install the executable file in /usr/local/bin. Uninstalling from pip (python2) removes the binary. So I had to uninstall and re-install in pip3 to get things working.